# define_method for setter wont work inside class call

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming, page-object-gem

I'm trying to dynamically create methods depending on provided name like [page-object gem do](https://github.com/cheezy/page-object/blob/b577b2ab58f6d17bd9180932504cc55eb51d116a/lib/page-object/accessors.rb#L216). But In my case `c.custom =` just returning passed argument, like simple assignment.

In my original task I need to send method call with provided value like:
`self.send(method).send_keys(value)`

Also, I notice, when added `puts` to line `"called #{name} with #{value}"` and called `custom` from outside of object like `C.new.custom = 123` it will produce expected output, but still that's not what I want.

Is there any way to define required method, to call it inside and outside of object?

```
module M
  def create(name)
    define_method("#{name}=") do |value|
     "called #{name} with #{value}"
    end
  end
end

class C
  extend M
  create(:custom)
  def initialize(val)
    puts custom = val
  end
end

C.new('haha')
```

Comment: @cremno, thanks for link, but it's not my problem. As @engineersmnky notice - I'm assigning to local variable there. I should use `self.custom = 'value'` to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
module M
  def create(name)
    define_method("#{name}=") do |value|
     "called #{name} with #{value}"
    end
  end
end

class C
  extend M
  create(:custom)
  def initialize(val)
    puts public_send(:custom=, val) # this is the only change needed
  end
end

C.new('haha')
# called custom with haha
```

I only had to change one line in your code.

There were two problems with your code:

1. `custom = val` is not a method call, it assigns to a local variable named `custom`. If you want to call a setter, you need to make it explicit that you are calling a method, by providing an explicit receiver: `self.custom = val`. See [*Why do Ruby setters need “`self.`” qualification within the class?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44715/2988)
2. Assignments evaluate to the right-hand side of the assignment. The return value of a setter method is ignored, unless you don't use assignment syntax, i.e. `public_send`. See [*Why does irb echo the right hand side of an assignment instead of the return value in the case of a setter method?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30382543/2988)

Comment: thanks for great answer, my actual case have only 1st problem, so using `self` fixed my problem.

Comment: Would it be okay for you to close this question as a duplicate of the one linked in my answer?